# Should I combine these tables into one, or keep them seperate?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

In a question/answer forum component I am writing as part of a site, I have two tables that theoretically look like this(that is, I want said data kept for each entity):

```
THREAD                 POST
thread_id              post_id   
type_id (question)     writer_id
writer_id              thread_id  
title                  parent_id
body (optional)        post_body
followers              date
merge_id               upvotes
date                   dnvotes
upvotes                replies
dnvotes                views
replies                post_type_id (e.g. answer, comment to an answer etc.)
views
anonymous
```

The only real differences between these entities are merge_id (if a question is merged into another one, this id will reference said question_id), followers, and title. Combining them into one seems a bit cumbersome and bloated to me, and seems to be starting off a bit denormalized I think. And, if they're one, both body and title would have to be be nullable which they shouldn't (I know there can be safeguards in the code).

I also thought of having thread consist of only the attributes not in post which would look like:

```
THREAD
thread_id (or post_id which would be primary and foreign key refing POST)
title
merge_id
followers
```

but that doesn't feel quite right either.

Also, if it makes any difference, I plan to have the questions displayed along with the highest ranking answer quite often, in the style of quora.

Any design advice would be much appreciated.

(also, I am keeping them someone generic (thread/post) so that if needed I can use these tables for a blog or whatever else later on.)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html

Comment: This is a faq. Google 'stackoverflow.com philipxy database subtyping'.

Comment: the presentation of you tables in your post is rather strange.Usually one does not write two lists (of columns) side by side.This makes them hard to use. Assume that somebody wants to copy the list of columns of the thread table to use it in his answer. A simple editor (as provided by most browsers) could not handle this efficiently. One has to copy the columns word by word. The columns in a line aren't related so I cannot see any advantage in representing this in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like these should be two separate tables.

To help you with the decision, find out how you are going to use them.

If you treat them the same in your SQL queries, and you usually don't care if something is a post or a thread, using a single table would make sense.
If you treat them differently (which I'd expect), use two tables.